# How to configure Solr keyword redirect to get two random products?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

The idea is to obtain search result with   any 2 products on the result page by certain keyword.
Is it possible somehow to restrict nubmer of results on the page with keyword redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

- Create a new category
- Assign the new category to the ProductS
- Create a Solr keyword redirect to the new category

Comment: Simple and clear, thank you!